# Update column values google sheet python

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I'm new to google sheet python, and I want to know that there is any method which takes column number(55) or title(CM) as an argument and provide me the updated column value.

or

Any code which returns me a new input value or updated value of the given column.

Example:

[image]

There are 6 values available in the CM column, and when seven value appears in the same column, so I want a method which returns me the exact value which occurs in the CM column.

If there a way or any method which provides me the updated or new column value, then it's very helpful to me.

I'm going to run an infinite loop and put the method in it that returns me the value when any input occurs in the given column at any position.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your question, I cannot understand about the current issue of your script and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Do you want the last value? In your example `25`? Or _all_ the values in the column? In any case, have you considered using an [`onEdit` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) - this would trigger a script every time there was an edit in your script. As I believe you are intending to make many requests constantly and this exhaust your quota very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggested approach:

1.) I used Apps Script to create a trigger whenever the user edit CM column. When the user edit CM column (update value or add a new value), the script will show the following information from CO to CR (Row 2):

- CO - Type (Update or New - updates a value o new added value)
- CP - Row (The edited row number in the column CM)
- CQ - Old value (For "updated" value, it will show the old value. For
  "new" value, it will show an empty value in the cell)
- CR - New value (For "updated" value, it will show the updated value.
  For "new" value, it will show the new added value in the cell)

2.) Use python script to monitor the changes of those values via Google Sheet API.

3.) Google Sheet API does not support onEdit. It does not monitor the changes in the cell.

Here's my script that I used to achieve the target:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //Get edited cell
  var range = e.range;
  //Ignore the event if editing the other column but not the column CM
  //Ignore the event if deleting the cell value
  if (range.getA1Notation().indexOf("CM") != 0 || (e.oldValue == null && e.value == null)) {
    return;
  }
  
  //Get the current active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //Get to range "CO2:CR2". The result will show in this range
  //CO2 is Type (New or Update)
  //CP2 is Row. Which row in the column is updated
  //CQ2 is the old value. For the type 'Update', it will show the old value. For the type 'New', it will show empty value
  //CR2 is the new value. It will show the updated value for the type 'Update' or it will show the new added value for the type 'New'
  var resultRange = sheet.getRange("CO2:CR2");
  
  //Show the result
  resultRange.setValues([[e.oldValue == null ? "New":"Update", range.getRow(), e.oldValue, e.value]])  
}
```

Here's the sample result in my spreadsheet:

[image]

As you can see, I changed the value of CM6 from 60 to 25, and the results showed in CQ2(the old value) and CR2(the new value).